# Closing popup window after 3 seconds

Tags: javascript, html

I need to close the popup windows in the following after 3 seconds. How do I do it.

```
<map id="ImgMap0" name="ImgMap0">
                  <area alt="" coords="127, 22, 20" alt="" title="click here" href="includes/popup1.htm" onclick="javascript:void window.open

('includes/popup1.htm','1366002941508','width=500,height=200,left=375,top=330');return false;" shape="circle" />
</map></p>
```

Comment: Use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close automatically a webpage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621554/how-to-close-automatically-a-webpage)

Answer (score 16):

Use a setTimeout, for example:

```
var win = window.open("http://www.google.com", '1366002941508','width=500,height=200,left=375,top=330');

setTimeout(function () { win.close();}, 3000);
```

Sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N5rve/

Answer (score 14):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function closeWindow() {
    setTimeout(function() {
    window.close();
    }, 3000);
    }

    window.onload = closeWindow();
    </script>
```

That should do it.

Comment: It only works when called right after the window has been opened.  It looks like it doesn't work asynchronously.

Answer (score 3):

```
<area alt="" coords="127, 22, 20" alt="" title="click here" href="includes/popup1.htm" onclick="openWindow()" shape="circle" />

function openWindow(){
    var win = window.open('includes/popup1.htm', '1366002941508',  'width=500,height=200,left=375,top=330');
    setTimeout(function(){
        win.close()
    }, 3000);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @leo_ap this appears to be an exact duplicate of [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16127137/421245).

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Opens a (popup) window with whatever content and close it after 3 seconds. thanks @leo_ap

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<area alt="" coords="127, 22, 20" alt="" title="click here" href="includes/popup1.htm" onclick="openWindow()" shape="circle" />

function openWindow(){
    var win = window.open('includes/popup1.htm', '1366002941508',  'width=500,height=200,left=375,top=330');
    setTimeout(function(){
        win.close()
    }, 3000);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Arun P Johny: Didn't work at all. Should the 2 code elements be separate or should they be combined in smoe way. Total newbie so you are going to have to spell it out to me.

Answer (score 0):

use this tutorials to get what you want

http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function close_popup(){
        //code here...
     }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body onLoad="setTimeout('close_popup()', 3000)"> // 3000 milisec = 3sec

 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a global variable and reuse it in our code.

```js
var info = function (text, onClose, headerText) {
              if (!headerText)
                headerText = "Info";
    
            alert(text, null, onClose, headerText, true);
    }
    
    // Call this in own code where ever you need
    
    info("Message that going to close automatic.");
    hidePopUpMessage();
    
    // callback function to showing 3 sec.
    function hidePopUpMessage() {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#pp-alert-close").click();
                //$("#popup-close").click();
            }, 3000);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

winpop  = window.open("UnBlockPopUp.html");

if(!winpop || winpop.closed)alert("Popups are required");

setTimeout(function(){

winpop.close()

}, 3000);

Answer (score -3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function popup() {
        var myPopup = window.open('includes/popup1.htm','1366002941508','width=500,height=200,left=375,top=330');
        var t=setTimeout(myPopup.close(),3000);
        return false;
    }
</script>
<map id="ImgMap0" name="ImgMap0">
    <area alt="" coords="127, 22, 20" alt="" title="click here" href="includes/popup1.htm" onclick="popup();" shape="circle" />
</map>
```