# How to close Model window using a timer

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
$scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'searchModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl22',
      size: size,
      backdrop:'static',
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });
    }
```

I am calling it like `$scope.open();` in my controller. The above function is outside controller. I need to close `$scope.open()` after 3 seconds automatically. How can I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127115/closing-popup-window-after-3-seconds

Comment: Are you trying to close it after they close ti themselves, or do you mean 3 seconds after it opens?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `close` or `dismiss` methods of [`modalInstance`](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal): `close` will resolve modal promise, and `dismiss` - will reject it:

```
$scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'searchModalContent.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl22',
        size: size,
        backdrop: 'static',
        resolve: {
            items: function () {
                return $scope.items;
            }
        }
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        modalInstance.close();
    }, 3000);
}
```

Of course, you can call setTimeout in `ModalInstanceCtrl22` controller too, just inject `$modalInstance` service in it.

Comment: I want to KISS you right now dfsg. God help u everywhere and your wishes come true right now man, I love you. You just saved my job.

Comment: Also @SydneyBuildings, it's a good habit to use the angular `$timeout` (which you'd have to inject into your controller.

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS In this case it's not necessary. I would say it's better to use `setTimeout` in cases like this when it's not needed to kick off new digest.

Comment: @dfsq Very true! You're right, why waste the processing power on a digest here. Nevermind then :)