# Javascript link that creates new tab and closes it after 5 seconds in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

What I should do to close after 5 seconds that newly opended tab in Chrome?

```
var link = $("<a />", {
          target: "_blank",
          text: "Phone",
          href: 'www.google.com'});

$("body").append(link);
```

Here is codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gMOQJK?editors=0010

Comment: have you googled at all?? see -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127115/closing-popup-window-after-3-seconds

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be achieved due to sandbox attribute.
You can have a look at it at : [Here](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#attr-iframe-sandbox)

Try code :

```
var win = window.open("http://www.google.com");

setTimeout(function () { win.close();}, 5000);
```

into the console and it will work fine. but when you will write this code in your application it will give error.

Please view https://jsfiddle.net/xjyw26hy/2/ , open console before clicking link  to view error of sandbox.

Please let me know if its helpful for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use setTimeout(function, timeInMiliseconds, paramaters)
Here is a link to the code running:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOEVQb?editors=0010

```
var link = $("<a />", {
  target: "_blank",
  text: "Phone",
  href: 'www.google.com',
  id: 'link'
});

$("body").append(link);

function remove(id) {
    return (elem=document.getElementById(id)).parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}
setTimeout(remove, 3000, "link");
```

Comment: This removes link from body, but I wanted to close newly created tab.

Comment: Sorry. I missunderstood the question :)

Answer (score 0):

I have created this code ([jsfiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/321jd312/4/)):

```
var i = 0;
function open_and_run() {
    newTab = window.open("https://fiddle.jshell.net/fakePage/");
    intervalVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer(newTab,intervalVar)},1000);
}

function myTimer(newTab, intervalVar) {
    i++;
    if (i > 5){
        clearInterval(intervalVar);
        newTab.close();
    }
    newTab.document.body.innerHTML="<br><p style='font: 30px bold;'>" + i + "</p>";
}
```

I can manipulate DOM of the new tab successfully, but, when I try to close the tab after 5 seconds, chrome sandbox stops the event. It is possible to clear everything in the DOM instead of closing it.

Closing the tab works fine in Firefox and IE.