# Javascript close window

Tags: javascript, php, tabs, dom-events, dom-manipulation

I have a link in `page_a.php` which opens in new tab using `target="_blank"`.

```
 <a href="page_b.php" target="_blank">Open Page B</a>
```

In the page B I have a script that will automatically close the tab/window once the user is no longer viewing it. My script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleVisibilityChange() {
      if (document.visibilityState == "hidden") {
        window.close();
        console.log("hidden");
      } else {
        console.log("shown");
      }
    }
    document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', handleVisibilityChange, false);
</script>
```

So I have:

```
 localhost/test/page_a.php //loads jQuery
 localhost/test/page_b.php //doesn't load jQuery
```

On `page_b.php` I get the warning:

> Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.

Since I am in-fact the one opening the window, is there a way to make this work?

Comment: The window must have been opened with JavaScript's [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open), not with a `<a href="..." target="...">` link.

Comment: You can try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16127147/6512745
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window must have been opened with JavaScript's [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open), not with a `<a href="..." target="...">` link. See [`window.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close) documentation for more details.

One way to do this, for instance, is by listening for the `click` event on the link, prevent the default action and then explicitly open the window with JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // wait for the DOM to have loaded
  document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', function( e ) {
    let link = document.querySelector( 'some selector to get the proper link element' );
    link.addEventListener( 'click', function( e ) {
      // prevent window opening regularly
      e.preventDefault();
      // explicitly open with JavaScript
      window.open( this.href, 'MyNewWindow' );
    } );
  } );
</script>
```

There are possible issues with this, though:

1. Your users may have configured their browsers to prevent opening new windows.
2. If a user accesses `page_b.php` by some other means than through clicking your link, closing the window will not work either. You have to explicitly test whether the window was opened by your other window with [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener):

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     /*
        ...
     */
     // if this window has a reference to the window that opened this window
     if( window.opener ) {
       document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', handleVisibilityChange, false);
     }
   </script>
   ```

   But as you can see in the documentation, `window.opener` has its own issues as well.

Comment: Perfect! I simply added `onclick="{e.preventDefault(); window.open( this.href, 'MyNewWindow' );}"` to my `<a>` and `if( window.opener )` to page_b. Thank you for the detailed answer.

Comment: @DvirLevy Yes, that works as well and you're welcome.