# HTML, open link click anywhere on page

Tags: javascript, html

I  have code for clickable background that I want to use but when I click on background its always open. How to make this code to work one per day BUT at most easiest way possible... with cookie or something else. I really need help with this. Thanks!

```
<body onclick="location.href='test.html';">
```

Comment: So do you want to restrict the user to open the link only once per day?

Comment: Is pop-up ok? If it is, You could use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127115/closing-popup-window-after-3-seconds just edit the timer to Your needs.

Comment: yes, but this is full page not popup with close time. I want to that link appears daily.

Comment: Hi Gregor, no its not a popup. I want when I click on background, to open that link only once per day. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage`.

```
<script>
    function onBodyClick() {
        var lastOpened = localStorage.getItem('body-opened'); // You can use another identifier instead of 'body-opened'
        if (lastOpened && new Date(lastOpened).toDateString() === new Date().toDateString()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem('body-opened', new Date().toDateString());
            document.location.href = 'test.htm';
        }
    }
</script>
<body onclick="onBodyClick()"></body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict the user to open the link only once per day. You can do something like this:

```
<body onclick="openLink()">

<script>
function openLink() {
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
  var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;

  // As date object returns time as well. Which we dont need. So we remove that.

  if(localStorage.getItem('date') == today) {
    alert('come back tomorrow');
  } else {
    localStorage.setItem('date', today);
    location.href='test.html';
  }
}
</script>
```